# validate url array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writting a small script where the user adds urls to a textarea, I found this litttle function to validate single links:

```
function isValidURL($url){
 return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

but I need it to validate an array of links

I use explode to seperate each like this:

```
$urls = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']);
```

I understand that I need to loop the array of urls using a `foreach` but how can I get the foreach `$var` inside my `elseif`

**Example:**

```
function isValidURL($url){
 return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $valid);
}

$urls = array('http://iamvalid.com','iamnotvalid.com','http://iamvalidaswell.com');

foreach ($urls as $check) {
 $validate = isValidURL($check);
}

if($check != $validate) {
//  If fail
 $result = 'fail';
} else {
//  If pass
 $result = 'pass';
}  // if

echo $result;
```

*(used array instead of expode for demo purposes)*

**Update:**
[Deepaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292998/validate-url-array/12293077#12293077) answer works great but conflicts with my mysql injection prevention function

**Conflicting function:**

```
function sanitizeSQL($input) {
 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true){
   $input = stripslashes($input);
  }
   return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($input));
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Explode, iterate, possibly `trim` each value before validating. What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isValidURL($url){
   return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}

function sanitizeSQL($input) {
   if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true){
      $input = stripslashes($input);
   }
   return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($input));
}

$urls = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']);

$errorcount = 0;
foreach($urls as $url) {
   // next line fixes conflict by cleaning here rather then before
   $url = sanitizeSQL($url);
   $result = isValidURL(trim($url));
   // Do something with ur result
   if(!$result) $errorcount++;

}
if($errorcount>0){
  //Failed
} else {
  //Passed
}
```

**Note**

Try to avoid `mysql_*` functions use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: This works but it is conflicting with another function (see first post)

Comment: What unexpected results are you getting with tat conflicting function ?

Comment: Your code works without my function in place but not with, my function  "cleans" the textarea input before exploding EG: `$links = sanitizeSQL($_POST['urls']);
$urls = explode("\n", $links);`

Comment: Ok sanitize the urls individually after exploding. because if you sanitize before exploding you might wanna use `\,` as the exploding delimiter i guess!! can you print the value of `$links` after sanitizing ?

Comment: Thank you Deeepak, I put `$url = sanitizeSQL($url);` inside the foreach loop and its working now.

Comment: Yes thats what you got to do. Because if you sanitize the array you cant do it as you are doing now!

Answer (score 1):

Using your example code (array instead of explode) I suggest something like

```
function isValidURL($url){
  return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $valid);
}

$urls = array('http://iamvalid.com','iamnotvalid.com','http://iamvalidaswell.com');

$result = 'pass';
foreach ($urls as $check) {
  if(!isValidURL($check)) {
    $result = 'fail';
    break;
  }
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe a little bit shorter... ?

```
$urls = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $string));
$validUrls = array_filter(filter_var_array($urls, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```